# How do I delete files that are locked when no other app can delete them?

Tags: windows, filesystems, virus, malware, trojan

So I found out that I had a Trojan on my external hard drive. My anti-virus app killed it, but it has created a bunch of random files on my computer which cannot be deleted. These are image files. They cannot be renamed - using any method - nor can they be moved, cut, copied, permanently deleted or even opened (in any program).

How can we rid these files from our system?

I have tried:

1. Right-click > Delete
2. Shift+Delete (Permanently Delete)
3. Swearing

and then:

4. FileASSASSIN from MalwareBytes
5. Eraser program
6. sdelete program
7. several commands in cmd

but none of them have been successful. How can I completely obliterate these files?

Comment: Can you take ownership? Does it make any difference? I've used [MoveOnBoot](http://www.gibinsoft.net/gipoutils/fileutil/) successfully in the past for difficult files, up to Win 7, not tested with 8

Comment: @Moan it's the funnest one!

Answer (score 4):

Use a live boot Linux DVD.  Boot to it. Find the file and delete it

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a usb stick to DOS. (So Windows doesn't start, this way the virus doesn't protect the files from being deleted. )

Guide: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-1869892/making-bootable-dos-usb-drive.html